# Suddenly 100% of PayPal Recurring Payment Creations Failing for Visa, MasterCard, Amex

Tags: paypal, profile, payment, recurring

I'm using PHP from two different Web sites. Those sites call PayPal's Name Value Paid (NVP) API to create recurring payment profiles.

A week ago, about 40% of any attempts to create recurring payment profiles for Visa and MasterCard cards started failing. That wasn't too big a deal since, if you just resubmitted the exact same card details immediately, it would usually go through. On the evening of June 1, 2012, however, ALL of my Vias/MC/Amex profile creations started failing.

To determine if it was something in my servers, I logged onto the PayPal Web site to use its function to create profiles. That function failed with the same errors. PayPal returns a 10764 error for Visa/MC and a 10752 error for Amex. I then used PayPal's Virtual Terminal to create direct one-time payments using the same cards. All of those payments were successful. So, the cards are good.

If the consumer uses a Discover Card or a PayPal ID to create a recurring payment profile, that appears to still work. But without direct Visa, MC and/or Amex support, my entire business.

I've submitted tickets and called my PayPal account team. Their vagueness in answering my questions has been terrifying. They acknowledged the problem, but won't tell me definitely if anyone else is have the same problem. If it's just me, then I fear my business is dead since PayPal will surely fix, or never fix, the problem on their own timetable.

Is anyone else having the same problem? Does anyone know a work around? Can anyone suggest how I could escalate this within PayPal?

Answer (score 0):

James, you are not alone, I am seeing a higher volume of error 10764 as well starting on May 28th, but some payments still go through. My research indicates Paypal migrated their data center recently and has planned downtime for "database upgrades" but it seems to me they just don't have their systems under control at this time. It is alarming to say the least.

See also Paypal status page:
https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/site-status/pp-live 
And more reports from Etsy users:
http://www.etsy.com/teams/7718/site-help/discuss/10349393/page/6

This will get fixed, but who knows how long it will take.

Comment: Did you file a ticket with MTS team? https://www.paypal.com/mts See a response acknowledging the issue here: http://answers.onstartups.com/q/39677/16413

Comment: James, the issue with errors was resolved for my site by Paypal as of this morning, I hope you had yours taken care of as well.